# How to pass some more parameters to token endpoint web api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

i need to pass some more parameters  to token endpoint as

grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123&peop1=value&Prop2=value

to get the token

How can i pass these and where i can get them on the server

Comment: Looking at Startup.cs and ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs, doesn't seem like it possible right now.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 resource owner password flow defines these parameters. If you need to do something else when authenticating a user you should look into the Implicit Flow -- that way you can code a custom login screen to accept any data you need from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for OWIN but you can catch the idea.

Pass parameters:

```
grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123&peop1=value&Prop2=value
```

Get them in your authorization server provider:

```
public class YourAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    ...
    public override Task ValidateTokenRequest(OAuthValidateTokenRequestContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
        var body = reader.ReadToEnd();                         <-- you got them all!
        return base.ValidateTokenRequest(context);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to pass your authorization server provider in configuration:

```
...
var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    Provider = new YourAuthorizationServerProvider()
};
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
...
```

Comment: Is there no cleaner way to get the parameters from the body?

Answer (score 1):

On your OWIN OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider you can catch your paramter like this :

```
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    string peop1 = context.Parameters["peop1"];

    //You can pass if you need the parameter to your GrantResourceOwnerCredentials
    context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:peop1", peop1);
}


public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var peop1 = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:peop1");
```

Comment: This one worked for me, also it's strong typed. Thanks ^-^