# IdentityServer3 - pass language preference to Token endpoint request using Resource Owner Flow

Tags: localization, oauth-2.0, token, identityserver3

So we've implemented Identity Server 3, and we have an app that authenticates using Resource Owner Flow. We'd like to pass additional information with the Resource Owner Token endpoint call and pass in the desired language with that call and then on successful authentication, check in the database to see if the user has updated their language settings on the device so we can pass down the correct localized strings from then on.

We basically want the database to effortlessly sync with the device's chosen language so the user doesn't get English text if their phone is set to Spanish, for example.

Is it possible to override the login method on Identity Server 3 to pass additional information? Or is there a simpler way to go about accomplishing what we want to do?

I found this: [How to pass some more parameters to token endpoint web api 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667785/how-to-pass-some-more-parameters-to-token-endpoint-web-api-2) would that be the correct way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: That is a feature that is beyond the specs.

Comment: I kind of figured this and would rather keep this sort of functionality out of our Identity Server implementation anyway. Thanks Brock.